# How to connect to MySQL database using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'd like to connect to a MySQL database on localhost but i don't know how to make it. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee");
            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This error occurs and I don't know if this code is correct or not:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at javaapplication1.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Comment: Have you added the `mysql-connector.jar` in the build path ?

Comment: Please note that XAMPP is just a third-party distribution package which includes MySQL and other things. It isn't a product or a thing you interface Java to. What you are connecting to here is MySQL.

Comment: add jdbc driver for mysql on your class path!

Comment: Thank you, but i'm a beginner user in java, so could you tell me how can i add the mysql-connector.jar in the build path?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add mysql-connector-java jar file to your project build path or if you use maven add the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm a beginner user in java, so could you tell me how can i add the mysql-connector-java jar file to my project build path?

Comment: Download the java connector. Then If u are using Eclipse IDE you have to right-click on your project and click "properties". Then go in "java build path" and click "Add external jar..." and select the downloaded jar.